# Using Tag helpers; calling scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm a newbie with asp.net core & tag helpers.  I'm trying to use an [example from the web](https://github.com/kovalent/examples/blob/master/zipcode/index.html) to auto-populate the city / state from the zip code.  The example works for me if I use the web example straight up.  However, when I switched to tag helpers it stopped hitting the script.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //when the user clicks off of the zip field:
  $('#zip').keyup(function() {
    alert("here");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <form asp-action="NewGroup" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="Zip"></label>
          <input id="zip" asp-for="Zip" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="City"></label>
          <div id="city_wrap">
            <input id="city" asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="State"></label>
          <input id="state" asp-for="State" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: There's not enough here to help you. We need errors/exceptions, what exactly is not working, what is it doing versus what it should be doing, etc. Generally speaking, your tag helper should *not* actually include JavaScript. For example, if you're not referencing jQuery until the closing body tag, The `$` will be meaningless at this point in your code. Also, you can end up running the same piece of JS over and over if there's multiple instances of the tag helper on the same view, which could also prove problematic. Use the tag helper to inject a class, and then add global JS that targets that.

Comment: Thank you Chris.  I'll try to come up with a more succinct and helpful question